# nvm alias default does not persist across shells

Tags: node.js, nvm

I ran the following:

```sh
nvm install 0.12
nvm alias default 0.12
# open new shell
nvm current
#=> system
node -v
#=> 0.10.33
```

How do I set my default Node to `0.12` when system is 0.10.x?

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a little ambiguous. You can do this:

```
$ nvm use default
```

But you still have to run it each time prior to launching `node`. My guess after playing around with it is that it might actually be broken, because it sure sounds like it should work. Perhaps it's broken in alternate shells? I tried in [fish](/questions/tagged/fish) and I was able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: This does not persist between shells. The `alias` commands is what should persist between shells and that does not seem to either.

Comment: I'm using `zsh`. That might be the problem. Also, your answer still says `nPm`. Just want to make sure we are both talking about `nVm` (node version manager)

Comment: Whoops sorry yes nvm. Zsh is probably the problem - I bet it only works in bash.